# How to get rid of the trailing dash

Tags: ruby, loops

I have a program that will create work notes for me, it works, however there's a trailing dash that I would like to get rid of:

```
def prompt(input)
  print "[#{Time.now.strftime('%T')}] #{input}: "
  STDIN.gets.chomp
end

def work_performed
  count = 0
  notes = ''
  while true
    input = prompt("Enter work notes[#{count += 1}]")
    notes << "\n" + "#{input}\n"
    if input.empty?
      return notes
    else
      while input.empty? != true
        input = prompt('Enter work notes[*]')
        notes << "  - #{input}\n"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When run:

```
test
  - tset  
  -
test  
  - tset  
  - 
tset  
  - tset  
  -
```

How can I refactor this to get rid of the trailing dash at the ends of the levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you write this as follows.

**Code**

```
require 'time'

def prompt(input)
  print "[#{Time.now.strftime('%T')}] #{input}: "
  gets.chomp
end

def work_performed
  1.step.each_with_object([]) do |count, notes|
    loop do
      input = prompt "Enter work notes[#{count}]"
      return notes.join("\n") if input.empty?
      notes << input
      loop do
        input = prompt("Enter work notes[*]")
        break if input.empty?
        notes << "  - #{input}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Example**

Let's try it with the following prompts and entries:

```
[11:38:35] Enter work notes[1]: Pets
[11:38:39] Enter work notes[*]: dog
[11:38:40] Enter work notes[*]: cat
[11:38:41] Enter work notes[*]: pig
[11:38:42] Enter work notes[*]: 
[11:38:43] Enter work notes[1]: Friends
[11:38:53] Enter work notes[*]: Lucy
[11:38:55] Enter work notes[*]: Billy-Bo
[11:39:04] Enter work notes[*]: 
[11:39:06] Enter work notes[1]: Colours
[11:39:15] Enter work notes[*]: red
[11:39:18] Enter work notes[*]: blue
[11:39:20] Enter work notes[*]: 
[11:39:22] Enter work notes[1]:
```

We obtain:

```
puts work_performed
Pets
  - dog
  - cat
  - pig
Friends
  - Lucy
  - Billy-Bo
Colours
  - red
  - blue
```

**Notes**

- I've made `notes` an array rather than a string, hence the need for `notes.join("\n")`.
- `1.step` returns an enumerator that generates the natural numbers beginning with `1` (See [Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step)).
- `loop do` (See [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop)) is more idiomatic than `while true`.

Comment: This is beautiful.

Comment: I'm happy to be of help.

Answer (score 5):

`<< "  - #{input}\n"` will always append something, even if `input` is the empty string, so you can check to see if it's empty to conditionally append.

```
<< "  - #{input}\n" unless input.empty?
```

Comment: Almost but not quite. Since `input` is a string, it will be `empty?` but never `nil?`.

Comment: @Makoto well that was a whole lot easier then I expected. Thank you!